# Command to delete all two lines of a format

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to **delete all occurrences** of lines(2 lines) of the format below in a file. That is first line ending with { and second line has only one character }. If this format occurs n number of times, I want to delete those 2n lines.

```
anything....{
}
```

Example Input file:

```
abc {
a
}
bcd {
}
ecd xyz {
}
pqr {
    stu {
    }
}
xyz {
so
}
```

Expected Output file:

```
abc {
a
}
xyz {
so
}
```

Comment: I am new shell and have used commands like "sed '/<pre>/,/<\/pre>/{//!d}'". But this one I have no idea.

Comment: `sed '/{$/{N;/{\n}$/d}' file` deletes all of them. wrt *If this format occurs n number of times* you need awk for that.

Comment: I redirected output into another file. Does what I wanted.

Comment: How to repeat this operation for 6 times before redirecting to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this (by a shell script), if it's help :
stack.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sed 's#} #}\n#g' source.txt> file.tmp
grep -o '.*{ [a-z]* }' file.tmp | sed 's#{ #{\n#g' | sed 's#}#\n}#g' > result.txt
rm file.tmp
```

output

```
[root@localhost stack]# cat source.txt
abc {
a
}
bcd {
}
ecd {
}
xyz {
so
}
[root@localhost stack]# bash stack.sh
[root@localhost stack]# cat result.txt
abc {
a
}
xyz {
so
}
```

Comment: The dual `sed`s can probably be combined into one. In fact, the entire script could probably be collapsed into a single `sed` script without temporary files.